# How to solve printing error using malloc method?

Tags: c, pointers, malloc

The below code reads and stores the content of a .txt file into an array.
However instead of printing all the names in the file, it only prints the last line *Matthew 789* 30 times. My print function looks right but not sure where am I going wrong.

> main

```
while (fscanf( in , "%s %s", name, num) == 2) {
  array_of_students[i] = make_node(name, num);
}

printf("\nOriginal unsorted array\n");
print_array(array_of_students, 30);
```

> Function:

```
Student * make_node(char * name, char * number) {
  Student * new_student;
  new_student = (Student * ) malloc(CLASS_SIZE * sizeof(Student));
  int i = 0;
  new_student[i].name = NULL;
  new_student[i].number = NULL;
  new_student[i].name = name;
  new_student[i].number = number;
  i++;
  return new_student;
}

void print_array(Student * array_of_students[], int size) {
  for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    printf("%s %s\n", array_of_students[i] -> name, array_of_students[i] -> number);
  }
}
```

> txt file:

```
John 123
Walter 456
Matthew 789
```

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning the same pointer values for `name` and `number` for each `Student` object you're creating, and overwriting the arrays those pointers point to each time.

You need to allocate space for the `name` and `number` members to point to space to store the strings in question and copy them over.  You're also allocating space for too many `Student` objects.  You only need one here:

```
Student *make_node(char * name, char * number) {
  Student *new_student = malloc(sizeof(Student));
  new_student->name = strdup(name);
  new_student->number = strdup(number);
  return new_student;
}
```

You also need to increment `i` in the `scanf` loop:

```
i = 0;
while (fscanf( in , "%s %s", name, num) == 2) {
  array_of_students[i++] = make_node(name, num);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion sir. strdup did the job :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  array_of_students[i] = make_node(name, num);
```

But nothing's incrementing i when you go around the loop. Should be `i++`?

```
    print_array(array_of_students, 30);
```

Probably should pass `i` instead of 30.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
```

and you didn't use `size` here